# Creating a Child object in MVC4 - Parent's information not being passed to Create() controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following [HttpGet] Create() method:

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? parentId)
    {
        var model = new CreatePersonViewModel();

        // pull parent from db
        var parent = _db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == parentId);

        model.Parent = parentSet;

        return View("Create", model);
    }
```

If I'm creating a new Person from another person's Details page, I pass in the ID of that parent Person and then construct a viewModel with the Parent included.

The POST looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreatePersonViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var parent = viewModel.Parent;  // This is always null for some reason

            var person = new Person() { Name = viewModel.Name };

            // if it has a parent, build new relationship
            if (parent != null)
            {
                person.Parent = parent;
                parent.Children.Add(person);
            };

            _db.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("detail", "person", new { personId = person.Id });
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

For some reason the viewModel getting pushed back to the POST method never contains the Parent that was defined in the GET controller method.  How can I tell MVC to push the parent from GET to POST, without muddling the View with a hidden field for Parent?

In case it helps, my view is here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreatePersonViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The controller action will only receive data that is explicitly included in the HTML form.

If you want to receive the Parent object, you'll need to put it in hidden `<input>` tags.

Note that any data that comes from the client is under complete control of your attacker and cannot be trusted.

Comment: Am I wrong for thinking that this is inelegant?  I feel like I should be able to tell the server to pass data directly to the corresponding POST method, instead of sending data that is irrelevant to the client (and that needlessly exposes data to an attacker).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2062383: Yes; that's impossible.  The POST comes from the client; you cannot tell the client to POST something without sending that thing to the client.  Consider using server-side session state.

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless so how would the server know what data you wanted to pass behind the scenes?

You could use TempData to pass data and it will remain on the server until it is read by your next request. However I don't believe you need that here. Since you aren't using anything but the parent id and the name, store that on the client - ie your viewmodel contains only those fields- no entity in your viewmodel.

When you post to the server load your parent, assign a new child and save it. No sense sending the entire object to the client.

Also I would verify on te server that the current user has access to those records - if applicable here unless your application allows all users access to all persons.