# Can I pass data directly from GET to POST serverside for Create() methods in MVC4 Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Based on another question: 
[Creating a Child object in MVC4 - Parent's information not being passed to Create() controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917516/creating-a-child-object-in-mvc4-parents-information-not-being-passed-to-creat)

Does MVC provide a mechanism to send data from the HttpGet Create() to the HttpPost Create() without going through the client?  If I need to send some data to the Post method that is meaningless to the client, how can I avoid cluttering the Views and over-exposing model properties to potential attackers?

Comment: no, you cannot redirect to post

Comment: Fetch it from the DB in the POST method? You can easily send the Parent ID to the View and use that to retrieve. Alternatively stick the parent in Session and retrieve back in the POST, not that I recommend nor like that method.

Answer (score 0):

Your GET and POST actions are just methods on a class.  It really doesn't sound like there's any reason to use POST here, if your only concern is to execute a block of code under certain conditions.

Change your POST (drop the attribute) and make it a private method so it is inaccessible to the client.  In your GET, do whatever checks you need to do, then invoke the method.

If you *do* need to expose the POST, refactor the code in question out to a seperate private method that you can call from either GET or POST.  A better implementation would be a separate class with the method located there for reuse/testing/SoC.

Just a caution if you *are* working with a DB here...while there are some legitimate reasons to write to the DB during a GET, note that this is not the indempotent nature of the GET in most circumstances (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - as I mentioned in the other answer you can use TempData - however you don't need this. You are using nothing but an id and a name from your entity, just pass *only* those in the view model. You don't need the full entity.
On the server side ensure your user has access to those records. For example if I was editing a Customer record, I'd ensure the current user has access via something like:

```
var currentUsersCompanyId = GetCurrentUserCompanyId();

ctx.Customers.Single(o=>o.CustomerId = customerId and currentUsersCompanyId == customerId)
```

There are a variety of ways to do this based on how you control permissions - and third party platforms for .net such as Apprenda that help do this more automatically behind the scenes.